# Show: $\sum_{k=1}^n X_k$ convergent a.s. $\Leftrightarrow\lim_n \mathbb{P}(\bigcup_{j,k\geqslant n}\lvert S_j-S_k\rvert > \varepsilon )=0$

Tags: measure-theory, proof-verification

> > Let $(X_i)$ be a sequence of random variables. Show that 
> >     $$
> > S_n:=\sum_{k=1}^n X_k \text{ converges a.s.} \Leftrightarrow\lim_n \mathbb{P}(\bigcup_{j,k\geqslant n}\lvert S_j-S_k\rvert > \varepsilon )=0.
> > $$

Good evening! I only worked on $\Rightarrow$ yet. Let me show you what my idea is.

Define
$$
N:=\left\{\omega: S_n(w)\text{ does not converge}\right\}.
$$
It exists a $\varepsilon > 0$, so that
$$
N=\limsup M_{n,m},~~~M_{n,m}:=\left\{\lvert S_m-S_n\rvert>\varepsilon\right\}.
$$
It is $\mathbb{P}(N)=\mathbb{P}(\limsup M_{n,m})=0$.

Moreover it is
$$
\limsup M_{n,m}\subset\bigcup_{j,k\geqslant n}\left\{\lvert S_j-S_k\rvert > \varepsilon\right\}=\bigcup_{j,k\geqslant n}M_{j,k},
$$
So it is 
$$
0=\mathbb{P}(\limsup M_{n,m})\leqslant\mathbb{P}\left(\bigcup_{j,k\geqslant n}M_{j,k}\right)\leqslant\sum_{j,k\geqslant n}\mathbb{P}(M_{j,k}).
$$

So it follows
$$
0\leqslant\lim_{n}\mathbb{P}\left(\bigcup_{j,k\geqslant n}M_{j,k}\right)\leqslant\mathbb{P}(A_{\infty,\infty})=0\implies\lim_{n}\mathbb{P}\left(\bigcup_{j,k\geqslant n}M_{j,k}\right)=0.
$$

Maybe you can say me if my idea is correct?

Greetings from

Miroslav